# jQuery modal dialog causes error on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this little snippet, which works on FF, C, O, etc... but I got this error in IE:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What should I do?

```
<script src="js/pop.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do your other `<script>` tags look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make the script an explicit type "text/javascript" possibly. But other than that, I don't see anything completely wrong (without knowing what `.dialog` requires)

**EDIT** judging by the error message, IE either can't locate the code for .dialog or for jQuery. Which line is the error occurring on? (can you point it out?)

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` does exactly nothing. The MIME-type is not determined by this attribute, but the headers that are sent by the webserver. `text/javascript` isn't even the correct MIME-type. Stupid IE.

Comment: I agree, that it's not the problem, I just see it to be good practice. And embedded scripts don't have MIMEs (as there are no headers other than the one coming from the page itself, which is presumably text/html). IE is notorious for being presumptuous when it comes to absence of information. I tend to try to be as explicit as possible if I know IE is involved, and leave as little margin as possible for a MS developer to make an assumption.

Comment: Tells me the script that manages the `.dialog(...)` method isn't being included. What are the `<script>` tags that are before that line in the page? -- Or you're using an older version of jQuery (Are you running the latest version to be sure?)